# Windows binary for Sanchez GT.M

Tags: windows, database

Do there exist windows binaries for [sanchez GT.M](http://fisglobal.com/Products/TechnologyPlatforms/GTM/index.htm) database engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GT.M#Platforms) it can run on Cygwin, though it is not a "supported" platform.

Answer (score 1):

There was some discussion of a GT.M binary that worked on MS Windows platforms, but to my knowledge, the person who was working on it for their PhD didn't publish the work done.

I don't know if he changed topics for his thesis or simply got an "all but dissertation" PhD.

The source code for GT.M is available on sourceforge, so it is possible to compile it on MS Windows, however, the Operating System model is based on Unix rather than Microsoft abstractions, so while it can be done, it won't be trivial.